# JSON Simple read arraylist that is a sub of "Example"

Tags: java, json-simple

I need to read an arraylist with JSON simple in java.
I got the code but what should I write to make it read the tree "example-array" that is a sub of the main tree "Example".

Here's the json code:

```
{
  "Example": {
    "example-array": [
      "something"
}
```

What I tried is reading it like

```
JSONArray example = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Example.example-array");
```

But that doesn't work. Help please.

Comment: what library are you using to read in the json data?

Comment: also check your JSON to make sure it's valid  http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

First thing: Your JSON is malformed, you didn't close the array with a "]".

But besides that, try this:

```
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

System.out.println("=======decode=======");

String s="{\"Example\":{\"example-array\":[\"something\"]}}";

Object obj=parser.parse(s);
JSONObject jObj=(JSONObject)obj;
JSONObject jObj2=(JSONObject)jObj.get("Example");
JSONArray jArr = (JSONArray)jObj2.get("example-array");

System.out.println(jArr);
System.out.println(jArr.get(0));
```

Comment: Thanks! This will do the trick. And yes, I see now that the JSOn in malformed but I wrote it on my phone and it's not even a real code. I just did an example!

I would upvote you but I don't have enough points myself to do so!